# Trouble with aligning elements

Tags: html, css

I came across this issue where I cannot get mine top-box to organize the elements correctly. I've tried everything that I know off and cannot get it to work. I need to have my text 100% in middle and logo just to left but every time I try to do that the text moves to right and its offset. And the Navigation bar to be under the logo and text and that is centered like 100% of time every time I try.

I have a main div as a container, this top-box is a child.

```
<div class="top-box">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="Assets/Images/WebsiteLogo.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="webname">
          <a href="#">
            <h1>Universal Web Designs</h1>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="navigationbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Designs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Some CSS not all

```
.top-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 0 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-top: solid white 1px;
  border-right: solid white 1px;
  border-left: solid white 1px;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid 1px red;
  /* background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); */
  /* border-radius: 5rem; */
}

.logo img {
  width: 5rem;
  margin: 0;
  /* background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); */
  /* border-radius: 5rem; */
}

.webname {
}

.webname a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.webname h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: rgba(26, 184, 212, 1);
  text-shadow: 4px 2px 10px gray; 
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.webname h1:hover {
  color: gray;
  text-shadow: 4px 2px 10px rgb(26, 184, 212);
}

.navigationbar {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0.2rem 0 0 0;
  border: solid 1px red;
  /* border-top: solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 1px; */
}

.navigationbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigationbar li{
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

.navigationbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px rgb(26, 184, 212);
}

.navigationbar a:hover {
  color: #dc3545;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://codepen.io/Bertw/pen/dyNpoaj

Comment: You have a three elements, aren't you? And if one of them have a 100% width of browser, that how can you put another two in the same line? It's illogical. I guess you wanna put all of these elements in one line, so you should assign to each of them specific width. Please read about the grid system, like bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: @BertW I love your answer but I ran into same problem before where Position: absalute makes it so my logo is completely out of document flow and if I resize the window the logo floats on top of document. Any fix for that?

Comment: @DaLegacy honestly my first thought was to use flexbox, but it doesn't necessarily center the "Universal Web Design" h1 perfectly on the page, but rather centers the h1 and logo on the page, and I think maybe that is not what you want but here it is anyway: https://codepen.io/Bertw/pen/dyNpoaj. I will try a few more things.

Comment: @BertW yeah that's the problem I'm having if you manage to come up with any other idea doesn't matter if you change the DIVs or layout I just want to know if its possible to make Logo responsive and have website name in the middle at same time at this point I'm just curious.

Comment: @DaLegacy CSS Grid might do the trick, looks pretty centered on the page and is responsive. Let me know if that works: https://codepen.io/Bertw/pen/ExZNjaj?editors=1100

Comment: @BertW Both of the last answers work perfectly the flex and the Grid to. Thanks a lot I learned something new from you!!!

Comment: @DaLegacy great I will insert that code as an answer below feel free to mark answered or upvote, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to you question with CSS grid:

```css
.top-box {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 0 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-top: solid white 1px;
  border-right: solid white 1px;
  border-left: solid white 1px;
  
}

.grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 555px 1fr;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: solid 1px red;
  /* background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); */
  /* border-radius: 5rem; */
}

.logo img {
  width: 5rem;
  margin: 0;
  /* background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); */
  /* border-radius: 5rem; */
}

.webname {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.webname a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.webname h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: rgba(26, 184, 212, 1);
  text-shadow: 4px 2px 10px gray; 
/*   border: solid 1px red; */
}

.webname h1:hover {
  color: gray;
  text-shadow: 4px 2px 10px rgb(26, 184, 212);
}

.navigationbar {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0.2rem 0 0 0;
  border: solid 1px red;
  /* border-top: solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 1px; */
}

.navigationbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigationbar li{
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

.navigationbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 2px rgb(26, 184, 212);
}

.navigationbar a:hover {
  color: #dc3545;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.logo {
  width: 40px;
  height:40px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-box">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="Assets/Images/WebsiteLogo.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="webname">
          <a href="#">
            <h1>Universal Web Designs</h1>
          </a>
        </div>
  </div>
  
        <div class="navigationbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Designs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```